# probability of non-mutually exclusive events

Tags: python-2.7, probability

I would like to know if anyone can help me with this algorithm. I think this algorithm is correct for small events, but when I need to know the probability of large numbers (for 100 events, for example) and the percentage for 1% (0.01) the result is 1.0 (maybe it's incorrect).

```
def get_union(events, percentage):
    all_elements = [x * percentage for x in range(1, events + 1)]
    x = 0.0

    for i in range(0, events):
        x += all_elements[i] * (1-x)

    print 'Result =', x

get_union(100, 0.01)
```

Comment: What is that algorithm supposed to be doing, exactly?

Comment: The probability of 100 events should be approximately 0.8, but the result is 1.0. If you run this function for 7 or 8 events for example, the output is correct.

Comment: No, I mean in more general terms. Why do the elements in `all_elements` have different probabilities? Why do you divide by the inverse of `x` so far when aggregating the output? More meaningful variable names might help.

Comment: For example: Probability of 3 events in 1%. So, all_elements will be 0.01, 0.02 and 0.03. These are all elements that I need to use to get the union. The variable name is correct related to the characteristics of non mutually events.